# Launch IE Process as Hidden

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, process

I would like to be able to launch IE from c# WPF app as hidden.
The following code is correctly launching IE, but it isn't hidden.
It seems to be ignoring the Hidden flag.
How can I fix that?

```
            proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            string IEKey = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE";
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(IEKey, "Path", "").ToString().TrimEnd(';') + @"\iexplore.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForInputIdle();
```

Comment: Can't you use real headless browser?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov
WebBrowser control wasn't correctly handling complex redirects and Javascript.  Standard IE is now working well, but I need to hide it, or somehow display off screen with no flashing.

Comment: That does not explain why you can't use real headless browser so... I'd try automation instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried Automation just now. The target URL I use has redirects.  The event OnNavigateComplete2 is called on a page with a form that's autosubmitted by javascript.  The page isn't complete at that point.  After it exits the event handler then IE fully renders.  Is there an event that will be called when idle?

Comment: for testing purpose, try to set proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=false and add this line below it. proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; Let us know about your testing results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT.  Thank you for the suggestion, but I found that IE is still launched and visible after changing UseShellExecute and adding CreateNoWindow.

Answer (score 0):

I try to search further on this issue and I got this information.

> you cannot hide the launched web browser window such as Internet
>   explorer or Firefox by using the "Process.Start" method from a regular
>   window application. if we launch the web browser from a windows
>   service, by default, the windows service does not contains desktop,
>   therefore, no window can be showed

Ref: [Open and Hide Default Web Browser](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45c45263-b3ef-4c60-9a8d-d5373c1285cd/open-and-hide-default-web-browser?forum=csharplanguage)